# Why don't I have to use pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

On the exercise we have a vector of structures, and we need to invert the order of the vector. I have solved the problem without h using pointers, but my gut tells my I should have used then, and I'm  not understanding how is it possible to solve this without using them. I am a bit confused because I have not coded C for a while now. I apologize for the variable/structures names not being in English, but they s are very close and understandable by any English speaking person.

```
typedef struct{
   char *str;    
} elemento;

typedef struct{
    int tamanho;
    int capacidade;
    elemento* elementos;   
} vetor;


void vetor_inverte(vetor *vec){

    elemento aux;
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<(vec->tamanho)/2; i++){
        aux = vec->elementos[i];
        vec->elementos[i] = vec->elementos[ vec->tamanho -1-i ];
        vec->elementos[ vec->tamanho -1-i ] = aux;
    }
}
```

Comment: The term "vector" is not used by the C standard. You mean "array". But `vetor *` is not an array, but a - well - pointer. And you cannot get along without pointers in C once you deal with arrays. Whoever told you you can has no knowledege about C.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `elementos` field of `vector` is an array of `elemento`, what you're doing is fine.  You're swapping the first with the last, then the second with the second-to-last, and so forth.

When you do the swap, it does a copy of each field of the `elemento` struct.

I don't see a need to involve pointers in this case.

Comment: I understand the swaping, no problem there. I'm confused about it copying the contents. I would swear you could not do that with structs (non native types), and that you had to use memcpy.

Comment: @AmiguelS Assigning one struct to another does a field-by-field copy.  The fact that some of those fields are pointers isn't relevant in this case because you're doing a swap as opposed to a copy.  In the case of a copy, this would leave two copies of a struct holding pointers to the same piece of memory, and freeing the pointer in one would leave the other pointing to invalid memory.

Comment: Strictily speaking you cannot even access an array element without using a pointer. Because the array decays to a pointer before the index operator is applied. There is little you can actually do with an array itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot more work than necessary, but it works.

Let's say, for example, that your structure were a really big one with 1000 bytes, and that you had 100 of them. Your array `elementos` would then be 100,000 bytes of contiguous memory in 1000-byte chunks. Your swap function would copy a whole 1000-byte structure to `aux`, then copy 1000 bytes from the far end of the array to the near end, then copy 1000 bytes of `aux` to the far end. That's copying 3000 bytes per swap, 50 times.

If instead `elementos` were an array of pointers to the 100 structures (each allocated elsewhere, with `malloc()`), your swap function would only be moving 24 bytes 50 times, the structures themselves would stay put in memory and only the pointers to them would move. This is much more efficient, at the cost of the memory for the pointer array.

Comment: You are correct. That is what I would have done. But these structures are imposed by the exercise specification. The confusion probability originated exactly from expecting an array of pointers but having an array of structs.